# jaas scrypt login authentication

Tags: security, authentication, servlets, jakarta-ee, jaas

I'm trying to login user with jaas using Scrypt. I was using sha before and I could just login using:

```
 request.login(username, "password");
```

and jaas would make the check in the background. But since the method to check if 2 passwords match with scrypt is a check that returns a boolean I had to change the code a bit. I think my code is correct/safe but I prefer being safe than sorry:

```
// here I get user credential from the db
Usercredential uc = us.getUsercred(username);
boolean matched = false;
if (null != uc) {
    // Making the scrypt check to see if password entered by user match db pass matched
    matched = SCryptUtil.check(password + uc.getSalt(), uc.getPassword());
}
if (matched) {
// if pass matched I login with the db password value
    try {
        request.login(username, uc.getPassword());
}...
```

I'm worried about the fact I'm logging in with the DB value and not the typed value. I make a check to see if they match prior to that though so there should be no problem.

Comment: This password comparison should be within the Realm. `request.login(username, password)` should be all you should do outside of the Realm.

Comment: @MarceloBarros I still have to request the password from db though, which is what worried me